# Is there a way to link input from two different arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm having an issue with some school work where I need to create two arrays one for names and one for scores which allows the user to input into both arrays (i.e. Enter the players name:; Enter the players score:). Then I need to print the arrays in descending score and then ascending alphabetical. As a hint we were told: Using the string sort function combine the two arrays into one then sort.

However I can't figure out how to link the two values to one another so that if I enter Nathan with a score of 87 the two values can't be split apart.

This is what I have so far (with some things I was trying to get to work but couldn't):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string names[10];
    int scores[10];
    string combine[20];
    int count = 0;

    while (count < 10){
        cout << "Please enter a player's name: ";
        cin >> names[count];
        cout << "Now enter that player's score: ";
        cin >> scores[count];

        count++;

    }
    /*sort(begin(names), end(names));
    sort(begin(scores), end(scores));*/

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << names[i] << ": " << scores[i] << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This sounds very unclear (not untypical of assignment questions). What is the "string sort function"? Were you originally told to use two separate arrays or could you make one array that contains `struct` objects?

Comment: None of my teachers seem to be able to give decent instructions when it comes to what they want you to do (I find it very annoying) but here is a screenshot of the actual page: http://prntscr.com/76f6xh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to "link" them from the very beginning:

```
struct Student {
    string name;
    int score;

    bool operator<(const Student& rhs) const {
        return score > rhs.score || (score == rhs.score && name < rhs.name);
    }
};
```

That way, the sort is easy:

```
sort(begin(students), end(students));
```

Otherwise, you'd have to make an array of indices:

```
int indices[10];
std::iota(begin(indices), end(indices), 0);
```

And sort that:

```
std::sort(begin(indices), end(indices), [&](int a, int b){
    return scores[a] > scores[b] ||
           scores[a] == scores[b] && names[a] < names[b];
});
```

And then print according to indices:

```
for (int idx : indices) {
   std::cout << names[idx] << " with score " << scores[idx] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as combining the two arrays into one you can do something like this:

```
// create a struct that of type "result"
// that combines both name and score
struct result
{
    string name;
    int score;
};

int main()
{
    string names[10];
    int scores[10];

    // array of your struct - same number of elements (10 not 20)
    result combine[10];

    int count = 0;

    while (count < 10){
        cout << "Please enter a player's name: ";
        cin >> names[count];
        cout << "Now enter that player's score: ";
        cin >> scores[count];

        count++;

    }
    /*sort(begin(names), end(names));
    sort(begin(scores), end(scores));*/

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << names[i] << ": " << scores[i] << "\n";
    }

    // combine into one array
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        combine[i].name = names[i];
        combine[i].score = scores[i];
    }

    // Now sort the combined array

    system("pause");
}
```